# Firestore cloud function giving log issues

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I am running a Firestore cloud function and the output is expected but in the logs I see a error

> Function returned undefined, expected Promise or value

I am not sure why it says this when I am returning the batch. How would I remove this log error, as well as access the document TYPES so I can not use the ANY type.

```js
export const subscriptionAdded = functions
    .firestore
    .document(`/User/{userId}/following/{subscriptionId}`)
    .onCreate((change: any, context: functions.EventContext) => {
        admin.firestore()
            .collection(`/Challenge`)
            .where('user_id', '==', context.params.subscriptionId).get().then((snapshot: any) => {
                const batch = admin.firestore().batch();
                snapshot.forEach((doc: any) => {
                    const chars = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789'
                    let autoId = ''
                    for (let i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
                        autoId += chars.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * chars.length))
                    }
                    const userChallenges = admin.firestore().doc(`/Subscribed_Challenges/${context.params.userId}/myChallenges/${autoId}`)

                    batch.set(userChallenges, {
                        challegeId: context.params.subscriptionId,
                        subscriptionUserId: context.params.userId,
                        dateTime: new Date()
                    })
                });
                return batch.commit().catch((err: any) => {
                        console.log('Batch Error', err)
                    });
            }).catch(err => {
                console.log('Error getting documents', err);
            });
    })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in your handling of promises.

Indeed, you are returning the  batch, but its from deep within a promise chain.

At the top level, you are not returning a promise (or anything else).  Its a simple fix though, you just need to do:

```js
        return admin.firestore()
            .collection(`/Challenge`)
            // ...... and the rest of your code goes here as you would expect
```

Additionally, there's no real reason to use a template literal (backtick string) in creating the reference for your `onCreate` trigger -- and it could easily lead to an error or confusion (though I suspect it works here).  Regular single quotes are fine.

---

To answer your question about types, its probably best to just refer to the [SDK Documentation](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/firestore/latest/), but your call to [`get()`](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/firestore/latest/Query.html#get) from the query returns a promise that resolves to a [`QuerySnapshot`](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/firestore/latest/QuerySnapshot.html) and the [`forEach()`](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/firestore/latest/QuerySnapshot.html#forEach) callback is passed a [`QueryDocumentSnapshot`](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/firestore/latest/QueryDocumentSnapshot.html).  If you mean the documents themselves (e.g. the result of a [`QueryDocumentSnapshot.data()`](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/firestore/latest/QueryDocumentSnapshot.html#data) call), that would be a [`DocumentData`](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/firestore/latest/global.html#DocumentData)

They are all available in the `firestore` [namespace](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.firestore#type-aliases) in the `admin` module e.g.:

```
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
```

Would let you access `QuerySnapshot` as `admin.firestore.QuerySnapshot`.

---

I also noticed that you never actually read anything out of any document in the `forEach`.  I'm not sure if that is intentional or not.

Comment: That's not going to be enough.  There are a bunch of promises also being ignored with calls to `batch.set()`.

Comment: @DougStevenson Unless I misunderstand, since this is using a batched write, `batch.set()` [doesn't return a promise](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.WriteBatch.html#set), only the final commit does.  Though the result it does return can be used to chain `.set()` calls, it can also be safely ignored here.

Comment: Thanks guys for this. I do read just the id. But what I cant find is the interfaces for those types. I cant see it in the source

Comment: I've added the exact way to get the types.  Though, keep in mind if you're using typescript and not javascript (question tags say javascript, but I realize they were added by a later edit), you'll need to [jump through hoops](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/typescript) to make it work, and its not super smooth.